# Network access is disabled for Free Download Manager on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: download-manager

I use Free Download Manager in Ubuntu 22.04. I downloaded its .deb file from their [website](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download-fdm-for-linux.htm), and it worked fine for a few days.
Now when I try to download something, the confirmation window appears and shows a "Network Error" message. When I try to report the problem, I get an error saying "Network access is disabled".

My internet connection is fine. I think Ubuntu somehow disabled internet access for this software. How do I enable internet connection for this software?

Network Error:

[image: Network Error]

Network access is disabled:

[image: Network access is disabled]

Answer (score 0):

disable firewall

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Comment: That didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Simply restart the app, downloads should continue as normal. Click the menu on the right and choose quit. Pressing x makes it run in the background

Comment: I also did the above answer, disabling the firewall. If this didn't work for you maybe disable firewall and restart